# Why won't my jQuery Feeds plugin work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

This plugin should display RSS feeds in jQuery, but I'm not getting any output following the [docs](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds/blob/master/README.md).

HTML:

```
<div id="feeds"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#feeds').feeds({
    feeds: {
        feed1: 'http://rollingstonesofficial.tumblr.com/rss'
    }
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/XmY9d/30/

Is there somethign I'm missing?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for your responses guys. I should say that this problem also occurs locally in a Chrome extension.

**UPDATE 2**

These are the errors I get in the console:

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
```

Both occur in jquery.feeds.min.js on line 17.

Comment: Don't use `raw.github.com` like a CDN as it's not one. If you check your browser's console, you should see an error along the lines of, "*Refused to execute script from '.../jquery.feeds.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*" You can get a supported address from the [project's demo](http://camagu.github.io/jquery-feeds/demos/) -- http://camagu.github.io/jquery-feeds/jquery.feeds.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load file from `raw.github.com` in `jsFiddle`.

So, instead of including your plugin through raw Github, you can use

```
<script src="http://camagu.github.io/jquery-feeds/jquery.feeds.js"></script>
```

or you can put it directly inside `Javascript` panel.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XmY9d/32/)**

Comment: How bizarre. It doesn't work locally either - might there be a parallel there?

Comment: Just like @Jonathan Lonowski  has described, the problem is with the raw github and jsFiddle itself, so you can either include your plugin from different source or place it directly inside the javascript panel.

Comment: I'm using the downloaded file in a local folder - should there still be a problem? See my updates.